# Leaflet layer ordering after zooming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, leaflet

I have problems to understand how layer ordering in leaflet works and I'm completly new to Javascript/Coffeescript.

The code I'm working on is part of a Ruby&Rails app and can be found [here](https://github.com/ISAAKiel/radon/blob/leaflet_map/app/assets/javascripts/samples.js.coffee.erb). The idea is to

- setup a osm basemap
- add a heatmap of points
- let the user select a rectangular area as a selection tool for further stuff to happen inside the Rails app
- react to user zooming by changing the heatmap to a marker-cluster setup

The problem: Zooming causes the layers to be redrawn. So the user selection rectangle ends up under the transparent layers of the heatmap. I want it to stay on top. I tried to apply featuregroup.bringToBack() and featuregroup.bringToFront()m but it's not working as expected.

I wrote some [example code with jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nevrome/emwmc4xw/) for this stackoverflow question to illustrate the problem and my approach in a more simple way. You need [leaflet.js](https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js), [leaflet.css](https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css) and [leaflet-heat.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/gh-pages/dist/leaflet-heat.js) for this to work:

```
# prepare basemap
osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl,
  maxZoom: 18
  attribution: osmAttrib)

# initialize the map with basemap
map = L.map('map').setView([
  17
  75
], 5).addLayer(osm)

# coordinate vectors
lat = [14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
lng = [72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78]

# function: layer arrangement in relation to zoom state
arrange_layers = ->
  if map.getZoom() > 5
    console.log "1"
    heatItem.bringToFront()
  if map.getZoom() <= 5
    console.log "2"
    heatItem.bringToBack()
  return

#function: react to user zooming
map.on 'zoomend', (e) ->
  arrange_layers()
  console.log map.getZoom();
  return

# add circles to map
for lati in lat
  for lngi in lng
     L.circle([
       lati
       lngi
      ], 50000,
       color: 'black'
       fillColor: '#black'
       fillOpacity: 0.5).addTo(map)

# add heatmap to map
heatItem = new (L.FeatureGroup)
heat = L.heatLayer([
  [
    15
    73
    3000
  ]
  [
    19
    77
    10000
  ]
], radius: 25).addTo(heatItem)
heatItem.addTo(map)
```

**Edit:**

The solution for my problem was to change to Leaflet 1.0 and add some custom panes with defined z value. Now I can control the layer order. The corrected example code looks like this and depends on [leaflet.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.3/leaflet.js), [leaflet.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.3/leaflet.css) and [leaflet-heat.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/gh-pages/dist/leaflet-heat.js):

```
# prepare basemap
osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl,
  maxZoom: 18
  attribution: osmAttrib)

# initialize the map with basemap
map = L.map('map').setView([
  17
  75
], 5).addLayer(osm)

# coordinate vectors
lat = [14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
lng = [72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78]

# create pane
map.createPane 'circles'
map.getPane('circles').style.zIndex = 450

# add circles to map
for lati in lat
  for lngi in lng
     L.circle([
       lati
       lngi
      ], 50000,
       color: 'black'
       fillColor: '#black'
       fillOpacity: 0.5
       pane: 'circles').addTo(map)

# add heatmap to map
heatItem = new (L.FeatureGroup)
heat = L.heatLayer([
  [
    15
    73
    3000
  ]
  [
    19
    77
    10000
  ]
], radius: 25).addTo(heatItem)
heatItem.addTo(map)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) plugin creates a layer that sits in a `<canvas>` Element which cannot be ordered through `.bringToFront()` or `.bringToBack()` methods.

Your `heat` layer does not provide these methods, so your `heatItem.bringToBack()` will have no effect, even if it does not output any error.

You could give a try with Leaflet 1.0, with which you can use [`map.createPane()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-createpane) to create "panes" (layer containers) that you can order.

By the way, your JSFiddle uses Leaflet 0.7.2 (current stable version is 0.7.7) with former CDN that does not support `https` protocol. Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emwmc4xw/98/

---

**EDIT**

I do not know if Leaflet.heat can take a `pane` option (you could look at its code).

As a workaround, you can define it on all your other layers, like your circles. Then you can set their `zIndex` above or below `400`, which is where is the default [`overlayPane`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#map-overlaypane), where the Leaflet.heat canvas and your circles go by default if no pane is specified.

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/emwmc4xw/120/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to implement your suggested solution with Leaflet 1.0 but [failed yet](https://jsfiddle.net/nevrome/emwmc4xw/119/). Could you please give me an idea what's missing?

Comment: You should debug your JSFiddle using the "browser console": hit F12 on PC / Linux and Cmd + Alt + i on Mac. Make user your external resources are loaded in correct order: Leaflet then plugins.

Comment: Cool - this works. Now I just have to implement leaflet 1.0 into the Rails app and set up some custom panes. Thanks!